# Wordpress Inserting multiple checkbox values using implode

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-insert, implode

I'm trying to insert the values of my check box into the database using this code, its working but the only data that is entering the data base is the value of the last checkbox that I clicked

**Form elements:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sports[]">Football
<input type="checkbox" value="running" name="sports[]">Running
<input type="checkbox" value="triathlon" name="sports[]">Triathlon
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     global $wpdb;
       $sports =$_POST['sports'];
       foreach ( $sports as $sportt) {
           $sportt;
           }
       $array = array($sportt); 
       $sport = implode(',',$array);
           }
       $wpdb->insert( 
              'user_profile', 
               array(
              'sports' => $sport));
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST['sports'] gets submitted as a array of the checked/selected values. so there is no need in trying to turn it into an array with foreach() and explode().
You may need to use a loop function to put each value into the database.
Or you can use implode('what you will glue it with', $yourArray); to make the array a string to insert into the database. If you do this: if you want to turn the string from the database back into a array you can use explode('what you glued it with', $stringToExplode);

Comment: i tried your solution.. i put `$sports =$_POST['sports'];
                            $sport = implode(',',$sports);
                            $sports_out = explode(',',$sport);` i got and error **Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,**

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion haha you are suppose to insert the imploded string to the database. And whenever you get that string from the database and you want to turn it back to a array use explode.